# vectors and using the STL

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm new to C++ and vectors and have been try to experiment with some of the STL functions and am wondering how come this is not working. I'm guessing its because of my first and last positions, are they not allowed to be ints?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {

    const int lowest = 10;
    const int highest = 99;

    vector<int> scramble;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        scramble.push_back(lowest + rand() % (highest - lowest + 1));
        cout << scramble.at(i) << endl;
    }
    int first = 0;
    int last = 19;

   cout << "The maximum value is: " << max_element(first, last);


}
```

Comment: What is "not working"?

Comment: the `max_element(first, last);` I'm guessing I have to use iterators instead of ints or something?

Comment: Heh, yes.  How is `max_element` supposed to know you want the max of `scramble` instead of some other vector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to `max_element` documentation:[std::max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/)

> ```
> std::max_element  
> template <class ForwardIterator>
> ForwardIterator max_element (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last);
>
> template <class ForwardIterator, class Compare>
> ForwardIterator max_element (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
>                           Compare comp);
> ```

The first two parameters have to be `FowardIterator`, not simple integers.

You may try the following:

```
 std::cout << "The maximum value is: " 
  << *max_element(scramble.begin(), scramble.end());
```

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yeah, that's a good point  I overlooked. Updated the post. Thank you!